# Haskell multiparameter class (templated type class)

Tags: haskell

I'ld like to implement a general Gaussian function for scalars and vectors. In Ada or C++ I simply would choose template for this, but in Haskell it's a little bit confusing.

I would start by defining a class that can apply Gaussian operators, like combining or calculating the probability:

```
class Gaussian g where
  (!*) :: g -> g -> g
  prob :: g -> a -> Float -- Here, I want a to be depending on g

data Gaussian1D = Gaussian1D Float Float
data Gaussian2D = Gaussian2D (Linear.V2 Float) Linear.V2(LinearV2 Float)
```

, and I'ld like to have something like:

```
instance Gaussian Gaussian1D where
  prob :: Gaussian1D -> Float -> Float

instance Gaussian Gaussian2D where
  prob :: Gaussian2D -> Linear.V2 Float -> Float
```

But I'm not able to implement this in a nice way.
Would this somehow be possible with a multiparameter class without digging into the field of template-haskell, eg:

```
class Gaussian g a where
  (!*) :: g a -> g a -> g a
  prob :: g a -> a -> Float
```

? At the moment, I'm failing to realize this scenario when I do domething like:

```
data Gaussian1D = Gaussian1D Float Float

instance Gaussian Gaussian1D Float where
```

with error:
`Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘Gaussian1D’ has kind ‘*’` (btw, I don't understand why this error occurs)

Thx

Comment: Tye types are likely `(!*) :: g -> g -> g` and `prob :: g -> g -> a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write `g a`, for example in:

```
(!*) :: g a -> g a -> g a
```

It means that `g` takes a type parameter. That should for example work if `Gaussian1D` was defined as:

```
data Gaussian1D a = Gaussian1D a a
```

But that is not the case here. You can make a typeclass with two type parameters:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class Guassian g a where
  (!*) :: g -> g -> g
  prob :: g -> a -> Float
```

But this thus means that you can make an instance for any `g`, `a` combination. This thus means that `a` does not depend on `g`, or at least not directly. You thus can implement a `Gaussian Gaussian1D Double` and `Gaussian Gaussian1D Float`.

You can however make use of [*functional dependencies* [wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies) where the type `a` is determined by the type `g`. This thus means that no two `a`s can be used for the same `g`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, FunctionalDependencies, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class Guassian g a | g -> a where
  (!*) :: g -> g -> g
  prob :: g -> a -> Float
```

Comment: The functional dependency (Same as @Aplet123) works like a charme. I just had to add ```FlexibleInstances``` for the ```instance Gaussian Gaussian2D (V2 Float) where```. Thx for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 5):

This seems like a textbook use-case for [Functional dependencies](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies), a GHC-only language feature that allows multi-parameter type classes where one parameter uniquely determines the other:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

class Guassian g a | g -> a where
  (!*) :: g -> g -> g
  prob :: g -> a -> Float

instance Gaussian Gaussian1D Float where
  -- ...
```

Comment: Yes, your suggestion works very well, see comment on Willem Van Onsem's entry. (I accepted his answer due to the longer explanation )

Answer (score 3):

Others have mentioned functional dependencies. Another option is to use a type family to make `a` depend on `g`:

```
class Gaussian g where
  type Scalar g
  (!*) :: g -> g -> g
  prob :: g -> Scalar g -> Float


instance Gaussian Gaussian1D where
  type Scalar Gaussian1D = Float
  prob :: Gaussian1D -> Float -> Float
  prob x y = ...
```

Since you are familiar with C++ templates, this is vaguely similar to

```
class Gaussian1D {
   // ...
   using Scalar = float;
};
```

so that later on you can use `typename T::Scalar` in a templated context to refer to the associated type. In Haskell you do that using `Scalar t` instead.

The correspondence is not perfect, of course. For one, C++ will only fully type check your templated code at instantiation time, while Haskell does that immediately, on-use.

Comment: Hey, thx for the ref to c++. I was more thinking about the metaprogramming template feature, like ```template <typename T>``` and then initiate at compile time with const-ifs and is_same, like ```Gaussian<Float>```, or ```Gaussian<2DVector>```. The solutions with the functional dependencies are catching this a little bit more.

Comment: @blauerreimers We don't have `is_same` in Haskell since we type check things early, so no SFINAE. We do have some slightly related mechanisms, like closed type families, and the `Typeable` typeclass. Both are overkill for this IMO. FunDeps or type families should both work for the example you mentioned, so choose the one you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

A good reason to have a multiparameter class is to be able to switch the base numeric type from `Float` to `Double` at will.

We can start by defining a scalar Gaussian distribution type like this, with `f` as the floating-point type argument:

```
{-#  LANGUAGE  FlexibleInstances      #-}
{-#  LANGUAGE  MultiParamTypeClasses  #-}

data GaussianScalar f = GaussianScalar { mean :: f , variance :: f }
```

We do not put any type constraints here. Of course, the `f` data type is expected to be some `Floating` type. But the consensus in the Haskell community has been for a long time that type constraints are best given at individual function level on an as-needed basis.

Next, we define two mathematical utility functions which will come handy later to populate our instance:

```
gaussianConvol :: Floating f =>
                  (GaussianScalar f) -> (GaussianScalar f) -> (GaussianScalar f)
gaussianConvol (GaussianScalar m1 v1) (GaussianScalar m2 v2) =
    GaussianScalar (m1+m2) (v1+v2)

gaussianDensity :: Floating f => (GaussianScalar f) -> f -> f
gaussianDensity gd x  =  let  m = mean gd
                              v = variance gd
                              σ = sqrt v
                              r = (x-m) / σ
                              n = 1/(σ * sqrt(2*pi))
                         in  n * exp (-(r*r)/2)
```

We now define our `Gaussian` class with two type parameters, the first one being the distribution object and the second one our base numeric type:

```
class  Gaussian g f  where 
     (!*) :: Floating f => g f -> g f -> g f  -- addition/convolution
     prob :: Floating f => g f -> f -> f      -- probability density
```

We can now define a `Gaussian` class instance for our scalar Gaussian distribution data type, using the auxiliary mathematical functions defined above:

```
instance (Floating f)  =>  Gaussian  GaussianScalar f
  where 
    (!*)  =  gaussianConvol 
    prob  =  gaussianDensity
```

**Note:** one has to be very careful with syntax. The compiler rejects `instance (Floating f)  =>  Gaussian  (GaussianScalar f)`, as it is a class taking **two** type parameters.

**Sample client code:**

```
main = do
    let  gd1 = GaussianScalar 0.0 1.0
         x   = 2.0 :: Double
         y   = prob gd1 x     -- class function
    putStrLn $ "y = " ++ (show y)
```

Comment: I like your implementation of this scalar Gaussian very much. I just don't see how I could easily implement other operations on it, eg ```prob :: Floating f``` for Float but ```prob :: (Linear.V2 Floating) f``` for vectors , which also needs other operations from the Linear package. But I'll keep your idea for the case of precision-variable code